# Eclipse: Easy way to see if phone is connected?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm coding Android in Eclipse, debugging 50/50 on a MotoX and the GenyMotion Emulator.  Both break very often. My general procedure has been "if one stops working try the other".  I've come to realize how spoiled I was coding .NET apps in Visual Studio... anyway, moving on.

Often eclipse doesn't recognize my phone until I restart Eclipse, restart my phone, unplug and replug the phone, etc.  This drives me out of my mind. Really screws up my work flow.

Is there any easy way to check if Eclipse is recognizing my phone before I try compiling? ATM I just stare at LogCat and pray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can find it in :

Open Window -> show view -> other -> Android -> Devices

in this you will find all devices you plugin and emulators

you will also find in device menu command rest adb will  try to restart and  reconnect to your devices and emulators if in not plugin yet

Comment: All I have in the 'Window' menu regarding android is: Android SDK Manager and Android Virtual Device Manager

Comment: and you will find arrow in devices window with option rest adb will help you in reconnect your devices and Emulators , 
could you check the answer accepted :)

Comment: I shall in 35 seconds

Comment: Dunzo. Dude that 'Reset ADB' button is a life saver